# Why is this sql not recognising TargetPosition in IF statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, if-statement

I have 2 tables with roughly the same columns.

I want to update the Status column of table Orders depending on whether the sum of ExecSignedAmount from table FilledOrders equals Orders.TargetPosition

But this UPDATE statement does not seem to recognise TargetPosition:

```
  UPDATE [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblOrders] 
  SET [Status] =  (IF ((SELECT SUM([ExecSignedAmount]) 
                        FROM [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblFilledOrders] 
                        WHERE [OrderID] = 2) = [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblOrders].[TargetPosition]) 'YES' ELSE 'NO')
  WHERE [OrderID] = 2;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does _"does not seem to recognise"_ mean exactly? Did you try looking up the syntax for `IF ... ELSE`?

Comment: It SQL says invalid column name: TargetPosition and yes I have looked up syntax but am clearly not writing it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use IF statement like that in update query.

Try [**IIF**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx) in `Sql Server 2012+`

```
 UPDATE [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblOrders] 
  SET [Status] =  (IIF ((SELECT SUM([ExecSignedAmount]) 
                        FROM [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblFilledOrders] 
                        WHERE [OrderID] = 2) = [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblOrders].[TargetPosition]) ,'YES','NO')
  WHERE [OrderID] = 2;
```

or anything less than `sql server 2012` use `case statement`

```
 UPDATE [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblOrders] 
  SET [Status] =  (case when ((SELECT SUM([ExecSignedAmount]) 
                        FROM [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblFilledOrders] 
                        WHERE [OrderID] = 2) = [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblOrders].[TargetPosition]) then 'YES' else 'NO' end)
  WHERE [OrderID] = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `IF` statement like that in your update query. You can use `CASE` statement like this -

```
UPDATE [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblOrders]
SET [Status] = (
        CASE 
            WHEN (
                    (
                        SELECT SUM([ExecSignedAmount])
                        FROM [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblFilledOrders]
                        WHERE [OrderID] = 2
                        ) = [FX_PROD].[dbo].[tblOrders].[TargetPosition]
                    )
                THEN 'YES'
            ELSE 'NO'
            END
        )
WHERE [OrderID] = 2;
```

Comment: @ManInMoon: I assume you have used SQL Server 2008 version. Otherwise `iif` is good feature introduced in SQL Server 2012. You can use both

Comment: No, I have 2014. IIF is fine - just like to know why IF does not works like  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182587.aspx